# Writing every element in a group from its presentation

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

## *Problem*

If we have a group $G$ of order $8$ such that $G=\langle i,j,k | ij=k,jk=i,ki=j,i^2=j^2=k^2\rangle $, and we denote $i^2=m$, show that every element of G can be written in the form $e,i,j,k,m,mi,mj,mk$. The problem suggests writing out the multiplication table during the course of the solution.

## *Solution attempt with questions*

(I will edit with the multiplication table added once I convert it from $\LaTeX$ to markdown.

First question: How does this group have order 8? I can only find 7 elements: $e,i,j,k,i^2,j^2,k^2$. It doesn't make sense for the 8th element to be $m$ as $m$ is just a denotion for $i^2$.

Next question:

I've shown all the trivial answers:

Given by presentation:

$ij=k,jk=i,ki=j, ii=m, jj=m, kk=m$

Extrapolated with $i^2=j^2=k^2=m$:

$i^2i=mi$, $k^2i=mi$, $j^2i=mi$
(I use similar logic to find terms like $i^2j$ and $i^2k$)

Elements of form $x^3$:

$i^2i=(ii)i=mi, j^2j=mj, k^2k=mk$

Where I'm stuck at is determining what the elements like $i^2i^2$ are. For example, $i^2i^2=iiii$. There isn't a part of the presentation that helps reduce $i^2$ to a usable form.

If I'm looking at this completely wrong, I'd appreciate some advice or a hint towards the solution.

Comment: Hint: Take the three relations $jk=i$, $ki=j$ and $ij=k$ and multiply them together to get an equation $jk^2i^2j=ijk$. Note that the LHS can be written as a power of $j$ using the equivalence of squares, and that the RHS can be simplified using the $ij=k$ relation.

Comment: To clarify, you are saying the LHS can be simplified from $jk^2i^2j$ to $j(j^2)(j^2)j$ because of the property given that $i^2=j^2=k^2$?

Comment: Exactly that. And then the RHS can be simplified and also converted to a power of $j$ using that property. (Also worth noting: in your first question you mention the 'seven elements $\{e, i, j, k, i^2, j^2, k^2\}$', but three of those are the same element!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Since $i^2=j^2=k^2=m$, then $mi=im$, $jm=mj$, $km=mk$.
2. Since $m=kk=kij=(ij)(jk)(ki)=im^2i=m^3$, then $m^2=e$.
3. Since $i^4=e$, then $i^{-1}=i^3=im$. Similarly, $j^{-1}=jm$, $k^{-1}=km$.
   So, $ji=ijm$, $kj=jkm$, and $ik=kim$.
4. Using 1-3 we can simplify any word from $i,j,k,i^{-1},j^{-1},k^{-1}$.
   Hence, here is the complete list of elements of group $G$: $e,i,j,k,m,mi,mj,mk$.